# How to approximate the derivative of a stock price over time?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

My high school marketing class is about to do a unit on stocks. We're going to make "pretend" investments over the next month or so, and have a competition to see who has the highest gains. These are relatively short term investments, so I'm thinking that looking at trends will be key to success.

It occurred to me, that trying to approximate the derivative of a stock price over time could be useful to some extent.

I'm wondering how I could do that though, given stock price is kind of jerky and irregular, and is also technically discontinuous?

---

Sorry if this is a kind of stupid question. I have some ideas, but I'm not sure if they're the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a pretty astute observation. In mathematical finance,
a stock is usually modeled as a [geometric Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion)
$$
S_{T}=S_{0}+\int_{0}^{T}\mu S_{t}dt+\underbrace{\int_{0}^{T}\sigma S_{t}dW_{t}}_{\text{noise}}.
$$
The noise term causes the jerkyness that you describe. It turns out
that the above formulation has the property that its sample paths
are *not* differentiable.

---

If you wanted to take the derivative of a stock given by some sample data (e.g. $S_1,S_2,\ldots$ taken at times $t_1,t_2,\ldots$), you could interpolate between the points to make a function $S(t)$ and take the derivative of that function. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)).

Comment: +1 Like the interpolation idea, although it might be a little hard to implement

Comment: You don't have to reinvent the wheel; you could use an existing software package or a tool like MATLAB/GNU Octave.

Comment: Ya, still hard.